# Filter dates by its last two digits

Tags: r

we got a huge data with two columns, dates and temperature. The days have the  form YYYY.MM.DD. I need the row number of the days with YYYY.11.22 and the corresponding temperature. Tried out dplyr filter but could not achieve anything. I am not sure what kind of spaceholder I have use for the years up in the front. Thankful for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you extract the day and the month into separate columns and then filter on month==11 && day == 22.

The way you described it sounds like you were trying to define a matching pattern using digits, which I also would expect to not work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data frame is `df`, consisting of two columns `dates` and `temperature`, then you can try the code below with `grep` to find the rows with matched last 4 digits

```
with(df,temperature[grep("1122$",dates)])
```

Answer (score 0):

The tidyverse way would be:

```
filter_at(dataset, vars(date_column), any_vars(grepl("1122$", .)))
```

Assuming that dataset is your dataset, and date_column the column containing the date

Comment: Thanks a lot FrsLry for your fast and elegant solution!!! Cheers

Comment: If the answer solved your problem you can upvote it! Thx